# Maxwell equations and electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

How can I use the Maxwell equation to prove that electric field is the sum of a conservative parcel of the electric potential gradient and a non-conservative parcel given by the magnetic potential variation?

Comment: You don’t need Maxwell’s equations. This is the [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition).